# Import SCSS globally for react using node-sass

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

I would like to create `mixin` functions and use global variables from a global SCSS file without the needs of import the file for every `SCSS` file i am using.

I know that I can import a global `SCSS` file to every `SCSS` file manually and then yo use that "global" `mixn` but I don't want that the developer will have to remember to add it manually every time he is creating a new SCSS file.

I need a solution for `reactjs`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import your `global.scss` that contain global variables to the project parent directory, in react's boiler plate it's the `App.js`.

You may now use those scss variables to any scss components without importing the `global.scss` everytime.

Comment: I tried and it's not working... 
i created a global.scss in the app directory file and i imported it to the app.scss. while building i am getting an error message that the mixin function not found. Can you show a simple example?

Comment: I think it's not possible that you will not `@import './global-variables.scss'` to a component's scss.